# No method error for Capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, automated-tests, capybara

I want to add a tag to a tag field. To fill the tag field, I have to add `','`, or hit enter with a tag name, for example, `"Ezgi,"`. I wrote these steps for it.

```
When(/^I enter "([^"]*)" on Label field$/) do |arg1|
    within('.x-anchor-form-item', :text=>'Label') do
        find('.x-tagfield-body').click
        fill_in('', :with=>arg1)
    end
    if page.has_css?('ul', :text=>arg1) then
        within('ul',:text=>arg1) do 
            find('li', :text=>arg1).click
        end 
    else
        within('.x-anchor-form-item', :text=>'Label') do
            find('.x-tagfield-body').native_send_keys(:enter)
        end
        within('.x-window-resizable', match: :first) do 
            find_all('a', :text=>'Save')[1].click
        end
        within('.x-anchor-form-item', :text=>'Label') do
            find('.x-form-text-wrap.x-form-text-wrap-default').click
            fill_in('', :with=>arg1)
        end
        within('ul',:text=>arg1) do 
            find('li', :text=>arg1).click
        end 
    end
end
```

I tried to write so many classes to fill the field, but that didn't work. For the 11th step, I viewed a message like this:

```
undefined method `native_send_keys' for #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x00000005119270> (NoMethodError)
```

Does anyone have any idea for this case? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method `native_send_keys` in Capybara. The code you copied from was probably calling `element.native.send_keys(...)` but you shouldn't be calling that either.  Just call `send_keys`on the desired element - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#send_keys-instance_method .  In your case that would be

```
find('.x-tagfield-body').send_keys(:enter)
```

Whether or not that will actually work for the control you're trying to interact with is impossible to say given the info provided, but it will fix the "no method error" this question is about.

Comment: Thank you for the clue. When I tried to use this element with send_keys, the system shows me focus error. Or when i use another ways to fill that field, my entries are missing. I'm going crazy!

Comment: @EzgiNacar I would recommend opening a new question where you provide the HTML you're trying to interact with, what library you're using for the tags widget (if you're using a library), exactly what a user has to do on the page, the code you've tried to replicate the user, and the exact complete errors that code returns.